# Events not being sent to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, android-sensors

I am using react-native to develop an android app. I am using native code to run a service in the foreground. This service consists of collections the accelerometer sensor readings of the phone.

Starting the service returns a successful promise but I do not receive no events. The following is the implementation of the service class:

```
    public class PhonePositionService extends Service {
      public static final String FOREGROUND = "com.testnative.position.FOREGROUND"; 
      ...
      //Event listener for sensors -start
      SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
          PhonePositionService.this.sendMessage(event);
        }
    ...
      };
      //Event Listener - end

      @Override
      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
      public void onCreate() {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE); //get services provided by sensor manager
        mAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER); //specifiy sensor
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); //register it
      }

      private void sendMessage(SensorEvent event) {
        try {
          float[] values = event.values;

          Intent intent = new Intent("PhonePosUpdate");
          intent.putExtra("message", values);
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
...
```

The thing is not even a notification appears, I'm afraid the service didnt start at all. 
The Following is my Module which uses this service:

```
public class PhonePositionModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  public PhonePositionModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    BroadcastReceiver phonePositionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        float[] message = intent.getFloatArrayExtra("message");
        PhonePositionModule.this.sendEvent(message);
      }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getReactApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(phonePositionReceiver, new IntentFilter("PhonePosUpdate"));
  }
...
  @ReactMethod
  public void startService(Promise promise) {
    String result = "Success";
    try {
      Intent intent = new Intent(PhonePositionService.FOREGROUND); ///////
      intent.setClass(this.getReactApplicationContext(), PhonePositionService.class);
      getReactApplicationContext().startService(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      promise.reject(e);
      return;
    }
    promise.resolve(result);
  }
...
  private void sendEvent(float[] message) {
    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
    map.putDouble("x", message[0]);
    map.putDouble("y", message[1]);
    map.putDouble("z", message[2]);
    getReactApplicationContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("updatePosition", map);
  }
}
```

When I call startService() from JavaScript, I get a success. However no notification appears and

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('updatePosition', (Data) => {
      console.log(Data);
```

in App.js shows nothing.

Thus:
1) The Notification does not appear 
2) Given that the notification does not appear, the service did not start (even though the promise did not return an error).

I tried debugging the native code on Android Studio but logcat isn't working for me.

Comment: Please simplify your code down to what is broken.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what is broken @GetOffMyLawn. Thats what I need help in.

Comment: I am sorry to say that unfortunately those types of questions aren't allowed and will get the question closed (I am not trying to sound like an ass here).

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn got it, ill do what I can